# Mysql query - month

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1064

I am a beginner in Mysql and I have a table like this:

```
create table purchase 
(
    purchase_ID INT primary key,
    purchase_date DATE,
    purchase_price INT
);

Insert into purchase values ('1', '2015-5-30', '10000');
Insert into purchase values ('2', '2016-7-30', '80000');
Insert into purchase values ('3', '2017-8-30', '50000');
Insert into purchase values ('4', '2016-10-30', '90000');
```

Now the question is: find which month has highest sales for the year 2016.

NOTE: consider purchase price as sales.

To find the answer for this, I tried this SQL statement:

```
SELECT
    MAX(purchase_price) AS sales,
    MONTH(purchase_date) 
FROM
    purchase 
WHERE 
    CAST(purchase_date AS date) BETWEEN '2016-01-01' AND '2016-12-30'
```

and getting results as

```
sales   month(purchase_date)
----------------------------
90000         7
```

but I am getting error in month because 10th month had highest sales not 7, can any one advise on this?

Comment: Do you have strictly one row per month in the table?

Comment: Why consider purchase_price as sales? Why not consider sales as sales and purchase_price as purchase_price?

Comment: And why ignore sales on New Year's Eve?

Comment: sounds like you need to group sales by month to get a total, and then choose the highest total.  Something like this may work for you:  SELECT MONTH(purchase_date) AS mth, SUM(purchase_rice) AS sales FROM purchases GROUP BY MONTH(purchase_date) ORDER BY 2 LIMIT 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For using `MAX`, `SUM`, etc u need to do `GROUP BY` (aggregated query with `GROUP BY`)

```
SELECT MAX(purchase_price) as sales, MONTH(purchase_date) as month
from purchase where purchase_date between '2016-01-01' and '2016-12-30'
GROUP BY month
ORDER BY month desc
LIMIT 1
```

this query should work for you.

Comment: @ArjunMp you are welcome, mark the answer as useful

Answer (score 0):

> find which month has highest sales for the year 2016

```
SELECT *
FROM purchase 
WHERE purchase_date BETWEEN '2016-01-01' AND '2016-12-30'
ORDER BY purchase_price DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: What if all the sales happen on New Year's Eve? Maybe they sell champagne and party poppers?

Comment: @Strawberry WHERE clause is taken from OP's query without change - ask him...